# Avoid duplicate value in Firebase firestore using android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing some data in Cloud Firesore.
I have some screen with books and when I click the "like button" it saves the book into a collection called `WhishlistBooks`

Now, before I save the book into the collection, how can I check if the book already exists there?

I tried to use the following however for some reason it never add the book even if it doesn't exist:

```
ibWhishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ibWhishlist.setSelected(!ibWhishlist.isSelected());
        if (ibWhishlist.isSelected()) {
            final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            final Map<String, Object> whishlist_book = new HashMap<>();
            whishlist_book.put("UserID",auth.getUid());
            whishlist_book.put( "BookID", bookId );
            whishlist_book.put("DateCreated", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
            whishlist_book.put("Popularity",bookRate);

            CollectionReference WhishlistBooks = db.collection( "Users" ).document(auth.getUid()).collection( "WhishlistBooks" );
            WhishlistBooks.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            if (document.getString( "BookID" ).equals( bookId )){
                                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( BookDetailActivity.this );
                                View toastview = inflater.inflate( R.layout.toast_whishlist_exists, null );
                                Toast toast = new Toast( BookDetailActivity.this );
                                toast.setView( toastview );
                                toast.setDuration( Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                                toast.show();
                            }
                            else{
                                db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "WhishlistBooks" ).add( whishlist_book );

                                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( BookDetailActivity.this );
                                View toastview = inflater.inflate( R.layout.toast_whishlist_added, null );
                                Toast toast = new Toast( BookDetailActivity.this );
                                toast.setView( toastview );
                                toast.setDuration( Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Handle de-select state change
        }
    }
});
```

However, I have faced 2 problems here:

1) At the first time when the user does not even have inserted a single book, there is no collection called Whishlist so the task is not successfully completed.

2) for some reason it can't really find if the `bookId` already exists.

This is an image from the database:

[image]

Is there any tip on how to make it work so I could just add the book if it does not exist or to get a message if it already does?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to query the collection to see if the book exists using its ID.  It doesn't matter if the collection exists or not - the query will still tell you if the book is there or not.

Comment: But when I use the code as I posted above, it never adds the book to my collection because it only enters if Whishlist collection exists from my understanding.

Comment: Check to see if the result set of the query is empty.  That means the document definitely doesn't exist and it should be added.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry I cant understand. It does not even entering the onComplete since there are cases where WhishlistBooks does not exists.